# Equating factor form $ u^2 + 1 = 2v^3$

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, proof-explanation, unique-factorization-domains

From the equation ,
$ u^2 + 1 = 2v^3$, we can write, $(u + i)(u − i) = 2v^3$.

I read in a book **[1]**  that

> Because $gcd(u +i, u − i) = 1$ and $2 = (1 + i)(1 − i)$, using again
>   the uniqueness of prime factorization in $Z[i]$, we obtain 
>   $u + i = (1+ i)(a + bi)^3$

My question is that why  $u + i = (1+ i)(a + bi)^3$ (this is what I call *equating factor*) specifically? Why not -

$u + i = (1- i)(a + bi)^3$

or

$u + i = (1- i)(a + bi)^2$

or

$u + i = (1- i)(a + bi)$

?  is there a specific  reason for $u + i = (1+ i)(a + bi)^3$ or there are other possibilities ?

**Reference:**

**1.** Page 158 of An Introduction to Diophantine Equations by Titu Andreescu, Dorin Andrica, Ion Cucurezeanu

Comment: The $+$ in $1+i$ is arbitrary, you have no change with $-$. The cube is consequence of the primality of the factors: in example if $ab=216=6^3$ the only solution with $gcd(a,b)=1$ is $\{8,27\}$, both cubes.

Answer (score 1):

**Part 1:**

Since  $gcd(u +i, u − i) = 1$ and $2 = (1 + i)(1 − i)$, due to  the uniqueness of prime factorization in $Z[i]$, you can not write   $u + i = (1+ i)(a + bi)^2$ or  $u + i = (1+ i)(a + bi)^1$ because then  $$gcd(u +i, u − i) = (a + bi)$$  which contradicts   $gcd(u +i, u − i) = 1$

**Part 2:**

So, there are 2 possible cases, those are-

1. $u + i = (1+ i)(a + bi)^3$
2. $u + i = (1- i)(a + bi)^3$

***Now, we show that both cases require  similar solution.***

**Case 1:** The imaginary part of  $(1+ i)(a + bi)^3$ is $a^3+3a^2b-3ab^2-b^3$. Since, $u + i = (1+ i)(a + bi)^3$, so, $a^3+3a^2b-3ab^2-b^3=1\implies (a-b)(a^2+4ab+b^2)=1$, from this  we get two systems, they are-

$$(a-b)=1; (a^2+4ab+b^2)=1 \cdots \text{(System 1)}$$

and

$$(a-b)=-1; (a^2+4ab+b^2)=-1 \cdots \text{(System 2)}$$

**Case 2:** The imaginary part of  $(1- i)(a + bi)^3$ is $-a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2-b^3$.

Since, $u + i = (1- i)(a + bi)^3$, so, $-a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2-b^3=1\implies (a+b)(-a^2+4ab-b^2)=1$, from this  we get two systems, they are-

$$(a+b)=1; (-a^2+4ab-b^2)=1 \cdots \text{(System 3)}$$

and

$$(a+b)=-1; (-a^2+4ab-b^2)=-1 \cdots \text{(System 4)}$$

From system $(3), (4)$, we get $a+b= \pm 1$, this implies one of $a, b$ is negative integer (if both were negative, then $|a+b|> 1$). If $a<0$ then, $-a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2-b^3$ becomes

$$a^3+3a^2b-3ab^2-b^3$$

***which is exactly same as case 1.***

If $b<0$ then, $-a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2-b^3$ becomes

$$b^3+3b^2a-3ba^2b-a^3$$

***which needs to follow the same procedure   as case 1.***

***So, it is sufficient to solve one of the two cases, i.e. it is sufficient to solve  $u + i = (1+ i)(a + bi)^3$.***