# There are no integers $y$ and $z$ such that $1+3y^2=z^3$ where $y\neq 0$. How do I prove this?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

There are no integers $y$ and $z$ such that $1+3y^2=z^3$ where $y\neq 0$.

I wonder whether there is an elementary argument to prove this.

What I have done:
$$(z-1)(z^2+z+1)=3y^2$$
then there are coprime $a,b$ such that
$$z-1=9a^2$$
$$z^2+z+1=3b^2$$
where $y=3ab$ and $3$ does not divide $b$.
Then $$(z-1)^2+3z=3b^2$$
$$(9a^2)^2+3z=3b^2$$
then
$$z=b^2-27a^4=9a^2+1$$
Hence
$$27a^4+9a^2+1-b^2=0$$
which gives us
$$54a^2=-9\pm\sqrt{9^2-4(27)(1-b^2)}$$
we obtain
$$54a^2=-9\pm\sqrt{27(2b-1)(2b+1)}$$
I know the integer solution is
$$(a,b)=(0, \pm 1)$$
However, I am not sure why. Please help. Thanks

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2926269/equating-factor-form-u2-1-2v3?noredirect=1) suggests to use $\Bbb Z[i]$.

Comment: $4-1=3 $ is True but $$4^2+4+1=3.7$$ Since $7$ is not an integral square, then $z$ cannot be equal to 4. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: $z^2+z+1$ can be a square but it can't be  $0\pmod 9$ if $z\equiv 1\pmod 3$.

Comment: You might back up to $27a^4 + 9a^2 + 1 = b^2$ and examine what it requires for $27x^2 + 9x + 1$ to be a perfect square, or possibly how $9a^2(3a^2+1)$ can be $1$ less than a square.

Comment: @NumThcurious, suppose $(x, z, 3)=1$, then $x^2\equiv 1 \bmod 3\Rightarrow 1+3x^2\equiv 1\bmod 3$. where on RHS we have $z^3\equiv z\bmod 3$. This means $z\equiv 1\bmod 3$. Let $z=3k+1$ then $(3k+1)^3\equiv 1\bmod 3^2$. This is not competent with LHS of equation, so the equation can not have integer solution.

Comment: @sirous, Thank you very much. I think you mean $y$ instead of $x$. However $y=3ab$  then $$1+3y^2=z^3\equiv 1\pmod 3^2$$

Comment: @NumThcurious, You are right, I meant y.  I said if $(y, 3)=1$, this means  3 can not divide y , so y can not be equal to 3ab..

Comment: unfortunately, this must be the case since $z\equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a modification to reduce the problem to a simpler form.

I showed in comment that in case $(y, 3)=1$ then there is no solution. Now suppose $3|y$ and $y=3x$ and $x=z-t$, then we get following equation:

$$z^3-9z^2+18zt-9t^2-1=0\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space(1)$$
Suppose this equation has solutions a, b  and c, then we have:

$$(z-a)(z-b)(z-c)=z^3-(a+b+c)z^2+(ab+bc+ca)z-abc=0\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space(2)$$

Comparing (1) and (2) we may construct following system of equation:

$\begin {cases}a+b+c=9\\ab+bc+ca=18t\\abc=9t^2+1\end{cases}$

One solution of $1+3y^2=z^3$ is $(z, y)=(1, 0)$. The system of equations is consistent with this solution. We have:

$z=a=1\Rightarrow y=3(z-t)=0\Rightarrow z=t=1$

putting these in system of equation we get:

$\begin {cases}1+b+c=9\Rightarrow b+c=8\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space(3)\\b+bc+c=18\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space , bc=10\Rightarrow b+c=8 \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space(4)\\bc=9+1=10\Rightarrow bc=10\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space(5)\end{cases}$

You can search and show the system can not be consistent for other numbers.

Comment: The only issue is there is no guarantee that $a,b$ and $c$ are all integers. Only one can be assumed to be an integer. Therefore, it is impossible to exhaust all the possibilities.

Comment: The only way I can understand it is only by using Euler's identity $$(e(e^2-9f^2))^2+3(3f(e^2-f^2))^2=(e^2+3f^2)^3$$